# Running a script from cli

Tags: wordpress, database, i18n, cli

How would I call CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema($locales, NULL); from the command line?  Minor upgrade seems to have had an insignificant DB error and this line did not get called.

Coming from:  CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FourSeven.php line 654
Wordpress, CiviCRM 4.7.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `cv` (https://github.com/civicrm/cv) provides helpers for running PHP code via CLI. For example, to run a single line of PHP code, you might say:

```
cd web-root
cv ev 'CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema(array(...), NULL);'
```

The snippet you posted involves a variable `$locales` which isn't defined here. If you know the intended content (e.g. maybe `array('en_US')`) then you could plug that in directly.

Alternatively, maybe you could call that particular upgrade function `addHelpPreAndHelpPostFieldsPriceFieldValue()` directly. (This is not always going to work; it's a case-by-case judgment looking the substance of the function.) If it's appropriate, then:

```
cd web-root
cv ev '$u = new CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_php_FourSeven(); $u->addHelpPreAndHelpPostFieldsPriceFieldValue(NULL);'
```

More generally, you could copy the desired code out of `CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/php/FourSeven.php` and put it in a new file (`my-upgrade-fix.php`). Hack the code as desired and then run:

```
cd web-root
cv scr my-upgrade-fix.php
```

Comment: There's also an interactive shell based on http://psysh.org/ -- you can run it with `cv cli`. It should work nicely on most Linux systems. (Although the CLI experience may not be as nice elsewhere -- on MAMP, it's missing some PHP extensions to support tab-keys, arrow-keys, etc.)

Comment: WOW!  Seriously helpful!  Thank you.  I've been up/down/all around the forums and wiki for multiple different things and there's still tons of little nuggets like this.